# why is there an extra route on the end of my url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Ok i need to do a redirect and the redirect is good but i get extra stuff on the end of the url

here is my redirect

```
redirect 301 /cash_registers/index.html http://posnation.com/cash_registers
```

here is my entire htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]

# # Remove the trailing slash
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?posnation\.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.posnation.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?posnation\.com$ [NC]
# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under folder1.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/our_customers/
# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all those to insert /folder1.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /our_customers/$1

redirect 301 /cash_registers/index.html http://posnation.com/cash_registers
```

when i go the url [http://posnation.com/cash_registers/index.html](http://posnation.net/cash_registers)  i get all kinds of junk on the end of the url...is there a way to fix this

this is the junk at the end of the url

```
cash_registers?route=cash_registers/index.html
```

Comment: why the downvote cash_registers?route=cash_registers/index.html that is at the end of the url...if you clicked on it you would see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the links you want to rewrite specifically like so:

```
RewriteRule ^retail_pos/(.*)/?$ /index.php?route=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop_pos/(.*)/?$ /index.php?route=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

man, it's not a bug, it's a feature. this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

is actually adding that "junk" to the end of the url.
if you want to get rid of that - mean no query string - replace that line with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? [L]
```

i'm not sure though this was not intentionally there, so that it could break some other functionality in your website.